# How to use errno accordingly to the function called

Tags: c, error-handling, errno

Hi guys i have a problem that i can not find an answer for, so i thought i'd ask you guys :p

so i'm trying to make an HTTP server in C and i'm using "errno.h" for error handling but i don't know which error codes i should test for, to be more specific i want to check for errors returned by the functions: socket(), bind(), accept() etc.. so that i act accordingly to each error and not in the same manner for every error.

do i check every single possible error code every time i make a system/library call or i don't use errno at all???

Comment: With select functions, set `errno = 0;` before the function call and check for non-zero afterward.

Comment: @chux: There is no guarantee that a library function which returns without an error indication does not alter the value of errno. "The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html)

Comment: @Aristos Miliaressis  "hoping for a definitive answer... ", yet only gave SO < 20 minutes before accepting an answer.  Not that the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28885681/2410359) is bad, but give SO some time.  With tricky questions, it may take days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check for the error codes that means something specific to you on the call you are making, then genrically error on the rest.

```
 doFoo()
if(errno == EMISSING)
   return FooNotFound;
if(errno == EAGAIN)
   retryFoo();
else
   perror....
```

Comment: It's not a bad idea to check `errno` and clear it before using it like this... I just saw that someone commented in the question.

Comment: i was hopping for a definitive answer on which error codes i should test for but i guess there is no such thing as a definitive answer, i will have to do some more homework :p , thanks anyway..